# Division by zero error

Tags: php, division, divide-by-zero

I have this code throwing up the error:

```
<?php

    $val1 = $totalsum;
    $res = ( $val1 / $val2) * 100;
    $val2 = count($allcontent);
    $res = ( $val1 / $val2) * 100;
    // 1 digit after the decimal point
    $res = round($res, 1); // 66.7

    echo "Success: ";
    echo $res;
    echo "%";

?>
```

I have tried adding this line:

```
if ($res === 0) 
{ 
   echo "not eligible"; 
}
```

but it still gives the error. any ideas?

Comment: can you indent your code!

Comment: sorry, its the way its written in the script!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You'd want to check $val2 before the division occurs:

```
<?php
$val1 = $totalsum;
$val2 = count($allcontent);
if($val2 != 0)
{
    $res = ( $val1 / $val2) * 100;
    // 1 digit after the decimal point
    $res = round($res, 1); // 66.7
    echo "Success: ".$res."%";
}
else
{
    echo "Count of allcount was 0";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have the following in your code:

```
$val2 = count($allcontent);
```

If the `$allcontent` array is empty, then the value of `$val2` will be `0`, and you will essentially be doing:

```
$res = ( $val1 / 0) * 100;
```

As expected, this will cause PHP to return the 'Division by zero' error.

To make sure this doesn't happen, simply use an `if` statement:

```
if ($val2 != 0) {
    $res = ( $val1 / $val2) * 100;
    // 1 digit after the decimal point
    $res = round($res, 1); // 66.7
    echo "Success: ";
    echo $res;
    echo "%";
}
```

This can be rewritten using [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf):

```
if ($val2 > 0) {
    $res = round( ($val1 / $val2) * 100 , 1); // 66.7
    echo sprintf('Success: %d%%', $res); // % is used for escaping the %
}
```

It does the same thing, but looks a bit more cleaner, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($val2!=0){
  //Do it
}else{
  //Don't
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure $val2 is NOT zero before trying to divide $val1 with it. Try this:

```
<?php
    $val1 = $totalsum;
    $res = ( $val1 / $val2) * 100;
    $val2 = count($allcontent);

    if( $val2 != 0 ){
        $res = ( $val1 / $val2) * 100;
        // 1 digit after the decimal point
        $res = round($res, 1); // 66.7
        echo "Success: ";
        echo $res;
        echo "%";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -2):

I'm guessing `$val2` is coming out to 0. Make sure `$allcontent` is being initialized and filled.